# how do i fix Jackson duplicating fields when serialization if the leading camel case class name is single later long

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, java-11

This is what I have

```
fun Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder {
        return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
            .json()
            .visibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .visibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE)
    }

    val mapper: ObjectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().build()
```

now i am expecting the out put to look like this when it is serialized

```
val seralisedClass = mapper.writeValueAsString(TestClass("test1"))

{"aField":"test1"}
```

but i am getting

```
{"aField":"test1","afield":"test1"}
```

now if i annotate my files with @get:JsonProperty("aField") will sterilize properly but I don't want to do that for every field.
Is there a way to configure Jackson to do just that.
i have tried .featuresToEnable(MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING) but it didn't make any difference.

here is the test

```
 @Test
    fun should_serialization() {
        val serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(TestClass("test1"))
        serialized shouldContain """"aField":"test1""""
        serialized shouldNotContain "afield"
        serialized shouldBe """{"aField":"test1"}"""
    }
```

Comment: Please show the `TestClass` definition

Comment: ok, i just did.

Comment: Nope, that's just some test. Show your `class TestClass` definition